# Vertical menu creation for web application

Tags: web-applications

I need to created vertical menu  for my project on mouse over i need to display submenu and on the click of submenu the submenu should display in the left side vertically and the main menu should display horizontally.
[image: vertical menu]

On click of submenu the menu should look like this 
[image: On click of submenu]

Can any1 help me how to do this for web application in asp.net using c sharp